# Cargo bin's not added to path ( fish shell )

Tags: rust, terminal, rust-cargo, fish

I'm using the fish shell under MacOS X Capitan and after using rustup.rs I get the following message:

> Rust is installed now. Great!
>
> To get started you need Cargo's bin directory in your PATH environment variable.
> Next time you log in this will be done automatically.
> The next time I logged in Cargo was not in my PATH. I had to add it manually.

In my .config/fish/fish.config file I have a:

> set -x PATH ...

line where I had to manually add cargo bin's:

> set -x PATH ... .cargo/bin

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. run the `fish_add_path` command

> fish_add_path /home/your-username/.cargo/bin/

```
my path: fish_add_path /Users/aharo/.cargo/bin/
```

2. restart terminal/shell
3. Run `rustc`

Comment: Thanks, I was trying for 2 hours to change the env to be fish specific. This solved it

Answer (score 3):

Follow the steps

1. Open file `~/.config/fish/config.fish`;
2. Add the line `set PATH $PATH ~/.cargo/bin`; and
3. Restart fish terminal